# Text of the "verbs" tag wiki.

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I know verbs are tricky to define which is why I left that tag wiki alone for a long time. So let's work together on the best wording.

I think I defined it as words which describe actions, which is imperfect since nouns can describe actions too. But it now reads "words which describe events and states" which I think is even less perfect. I understand the editor was trying to improve it based on some technicalities of how verbs work in Japanese, but I think it has made it less easy for contributors who are already not good with grammatical terms.

I think naive readers would read "event" as a word to cover parties and concerts, which makes it weaker than "action".

As for "state", it's pretty technical but I think readers not as naive as the previous may read some confusion with adjectives from this since you typically use adjectives to describe what state an object is in. A bit like "condition" or "quality". This is probably worsened in Japanese where i-adjectives are pretty much a kind of verb -:

Since editing tag wikis is quite slow and painful why don't we give the wording a good talking through here and then we can add in the text we agree upon.

---

As a lesser point, I think the discussion of the differences of i-adjectives and na-adjectives within the verb wiki is a bit much. It's an important distinction but I don't think we need to put it in the verb page as it makes it too daunting to a reader who just wants a grammar refresher to make sure he's using the right tag. Perhaps we should just mention that i-adjectives are closely related to verbs in Japanese but not go much further and leave the rest to their respective tag wikis.